# Unable to setState on ReactJS component from outside React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am working on an application in which I update an interface with data that is coming in on a stream.  I am starting with code that is something like this:

```
var TempDisplay = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            tempFAA:0.69,
            tempGGG:1.4,
            temp03K:3.66,
            temp60K:58.79,
            rateFAA:-0.04,
            rateGGG:-0.0001,
            rate03K:0.45,
            rate60K:1.3,
        }
    },
    render: function() {
        return(
            <div>
                <Temp label="60K" color="#d62728" temp={this.state.temp60K} rate={this.state.rate60K} />
                <Temp label="03K" color="#2ca02c" temp={this.state.temp03K} rate={this.state.rate03K} />
                <Temp label="GGG" color="#ff7f0e" temp={this.state.tempGGG} rate={this.state.rateGGG} />
                <Temp label="FAA" color="#1f77b4" temp={this.state.tempFAA} rate={this.state.rateFAA} />
            </div>
        )
    }
});

var Instrument = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return(
            <div><span style={{color:this.props.color}}>{'\u25C9 '}</span>{this.props.label}</div>
        )
    }
});

var tempDisplay = ReactDOM.render(<TempDisplay />, document.getElementById("tempDisplay"));
```

What it seems like I should do now is call `tempDisplay.setState()` to update these temperature displays whenever new data comes in, but `tempDisplay` seems to be a `<div>` object on which `setState()` cannot be called.  How should I properly be doing this?

Comment: what do you mean by "when new data comes in" the only way the data in your state is going to change is if you replace it with new values... where are you expecting this to come from react is awesome but its not magic

Comment: Maybe it's better not to `setState` of `tempDisplay` component, but pass data into it using props? If data updates externally, you don't need to use component state to store it.

Comment: Like I said above, the data is coming in on a stream.  So no, not other React components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a state container like Redux: https://github.com/reactjs/redux

Instead of having each component manage its own state, you will manage all the state in the store. Components will connect to the store and update when it changes. The store will change in response to some action which might be an AJAX response, receiving more data from a stream or a user action.

---

Alternately, you could manage state for a tree of components in a component which is the parent of all the other components which rely on the same state information. Then pass down the relevant parts as props.

Answer (score 3):

The component manages its own state.  Are the temperature changes coming from a database?  Then you might need to poll it with an ajax call within a method of the component.

That might look like (pseudo-code):

```
var TempDisplay = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            tempFAA:0.69,
            tempGGG:1.4,
            temp03K:3.66,
            temp60K:58.79,
            rateFAA:-0.04,
            rateGGG:-0.0001,
            rate03K:0.45,
            rate60K:1.3,
        }
    },
    pollTemperature: function(){
       $setInterval(function(){ 
       $ajax( ... call to API route ... )
       .then(function(){
            this.setState(temps: newTemps )
       })
       }
    }
    render: function() {
        return(
            <div>
                <Temp label="60K" color="#d62728" temp={this.state.temp60K} rate={this.state.rate60K} />
                <Temp label="03K" color="#2ca02c" temp={this.state.temp03K} rate={this.state.rate03K} />
                <Temp label="GGG" color="#ff7f0e" temp={this.state.tempGGG} rate={this.state.rateGGG} />
                <Temp label="FAA" color="#1f77b4" temp={this.state.tempFAA} rate={this.state.rateFAA} />
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

Comment: I plan to set up a stream.  Every so often, a data chunk will come in that has a whole bunch of different statuses that together need to update the data in many modules like the one I show above.  I need a way to `setState()` in multiple components when this data comes in.